# Can I apply bootstrap style to one of my react component while the others with material UI style?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, material-ui, react-bootstrap

I am using material UI to build an app, while I need to insert a `HiGlassComponent` component in my page.

`HiGlassComponent` needs to use bootstrap style to properly display and if I apply the bootstrap style to the whole app, then it mess up with my material UI style.....

Is there a way to only apply bootstrap style only to one of my component while leaving others untouched?

Comment: At least, you can copy all the CSS from browser dev tools, if that's the only case you are facing

Comment: @keikai That's a complicated component... meaning loads of css to copy...